# Hibernate Update Parent Table and its Child Table , but not working porp?

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

Here i have two JPA Classes: TimeSheet and TimeSheetDetails

In this case i have a trouble with updation of timesheet, while updation the timesheet (master table) updated smoothly, but timesheet details (child table) generate new rows instead of updation and the link table also updated with the new values.....

Here what is the re

1)TimeSheet.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = AMAM_Constants.tb_name.TIMESHEET, schema = AMAM_Constants.db_name)
public class TimeSheet implements Serializable {

private long ts_Id;
private String ts_Candidate;
private Date ts_Sdate;
private Date ts_Edate;
private String active;
private String ts_Type;
private String ts_Status;
private List<TimeSheetDetails> timesheetDetails = new ArrayList<TimeSheetDetails>();

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = AMAM_Constants.tb_name.TIMESHEET_LINK_DETAILS, joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "TS_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "TSD_ID")
})
public List<TimeSheetDetails> getTimesheetDetails() {
    return timesheetDetails;
}

public void setTimesheetDetails(List<TimeSheetDetails> timesheetDetails) {
    this.timesheetDetails = timesheetDetails;
}

@Column(name = "ACTIVE", length = 1)
public String getActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(String active) {
    this.active = active;
}

@Column(name = "TS_CANDIDATE", length = 25)
public String getTs_Candidate() {
    return ts_Candidate;
}

public void setTs_Candidate(String ts_Candidate) {
    this.ts_Candidate = ts_Candidate;
}

@Column(name = "TS_EDATE")
public Date getTs_Edate() {
    return ts_Edate;
}

public void setTs_Edate(Date ts_Edate) {
    this.ts_Edate = ts_Edate;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "TS_ID")
public long getTs_Id() {
    return ts_Id;
}

public void setTs_Id(long ts_Id) {
    this.ts_Id = ts_Id;
}

@Column(name = "TS_SDATE")
public Date getTs_Sdate() {
    return ts_Sdate;
}

public void setTs_Sdate(Date ts_Sdate) {
    this.ts_Sdate = ts_Sdate;
}

@Column(name = "TS_STATUS", length = 25)
public String getTs_Status() {
    return ts_Status;
}

public void setTs_Status(String ts_Status) {
    this.ts_Status = ts_Status;
}

@Column(name = "TS_TYPE", length = 10)
public String getTs_Type() {
    return ts_Type;
}

public void setTs_Type(String ts_Type) {
    this.ts_Type = ts_Type;
}
}


@Entity
@Table(name = AMAM_Constants.tb_name.TIMESHEET_DETAILS, schema = AMAM_Constants.db_name)
public class TimeSheetDetails implements Serializable {

private long tsd_Id;
private String tsd_Po;
private Date tsd_Date;
private String tsd_DayName;
private int tsd_Hours;
private String tsd_HourType;
private String tsd_DayType;

@Column(name = "TSD_DATE")
public Date getTsd_Date() {
    return tsd_Date;
}

public void setTsd_Date(Date tsd_Date) {
    this.tsd_Date = tsd_Date;
}

@Column(name = "TSD_DAYNAME", length = 25)
public String getTsd_DayName() {
    return tsd_DayName;
}

public void setTsd_DayName(String tsd_DayName) {
    this.tsd_DayName = tsd_DayName;
}

@Column(name = "TSD_DAYTYPE", length = 25)
public String getTsd_DayType() {
    return tsd_DayType;
}

public void setTsd_DayType(String tsd_DayType) {
    this.tsd_DayType = tsd_DayType;
}

@Column(name = "TSD_HOURTYPE", length = 25)
public String getTsd_HourType() {
    return tsd_HourType;
}

public void setTsd_HourType(String tsd_HourType) {
    this.tsd_HourType = tsd_HourType;
}

@Column(name = "TSD_HOURS")
public int getTsd_Hours() {
    return tsd_Hours;
}

public void setTsd_Hours(int tsd_Hours) {
    this.tsd_Hours = tsd_Hours;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "TSD_ID")
public long getTsd_Id() {
    return tsd_Id;
}

public void setTsd_Id(long tsd_Id) {
    this.tsd_Id = tsd_Id;
}

@Column(name = "TSD_PO", length = 25)
public String getTsd_Po() {
    return tsd_Po;
}

public void setTsd_Po(String tsd_Po) {
    this.tsd_Po = tsd_Po;
}
}




public class TimeSheetDao extends HibDao {

 public void insertTimeSheet(TimeSheet objTimeSheet) throws Exception {
    try {
        begin();
        getSession().save(objTimeSheet);
        commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        rollback();
        throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        flush();
        close();
    }
}

public void updateTimeSheet(TimeSheet objTimeSheet) throws Exception {
    try {
        begin();
        TimeSheet obj =(TimeSheet)getSession().get(TimeSheet.class,objTimeSheet.getTs_Id());
        obj.setActive("Y");
        obj.setTimesheetDetails(objTimeSheet.getTimesheetDetails());
        obj.setTs_Candidate(objTimeSheet.getTs_Candidate());
        obj.setTs_Edate(objTimeSheet.getTs_Edate());
        obj.setTs_Sdate(objTimeSheet.getTs_Sdate());
        obj.setTs_Status(objTimeSheet.getTs_Status());
        obj.setTs_Type(objTimeSheet.getTs_Type());
        getSession().update(obj);
        commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        rollback();
        throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        flush();
        close();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
obj.setTimesheetDetails(objTimeSheet.getTimesheetDetails());
```

You should do the same to update the child to what you are doing to update the parent. I.e:

```
obj.getTimesheetDetails().setTsd_Date(objTimeSheet.getTimesheetDetails().getTsd_Date);
...
```

Comment: the above objTimeSheet.getTimesheetDetails() also  contained the all details that u mentined here like Tsd_Date, etc... So here what is the problem for creating the new rows instead of uptaion.

Comment: You are receiving a detached entity, and mapping it to an attached entity. However you are trying to to set the detached entities of the collection of TimesheetDetails to the attached entity. So, the provider thinks they are new entities, that's why they are inserted instead of updated.